# Creating a materialised view and dividing a column

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to turn one column I have into a decimal via a materialised view query and am having trouble doing so.

My Current column in the table looks like this

```
Search Exact match IS
5.32
```

I would like the following

```
Search Exact match IS
.0532
```

I am trying to achieve this through the this line within the "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW" query

```
CASE "Search Exact match IS"
            When "Search Exact match IS" > 0 then ("Search Exact match IS" / 
100)
             Else 0
         End AS "Search Exact match IS",
```

I am however met with this error message;

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision = boolean
LINE 32:             When "Search Exact match IS" > 0 then ("Search E...
                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision = boolean
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might 
need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 558
```

Should I try and find a solution with this through a case?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your table structure and also the create command your tried?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
CASE "Search Exact match IS"
        When "Search Exact match IS" > 0 then ("Search Exact match IS" / 100)
         Else 0
     End AS "Search Exact match IS",
```

To this:

```
CASE
    When "Search Exact match IS" > 0 then ("Search Exact match IS" / 100)
    Else 0
End AS "Search Exact match IS",
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE